# BigQuery destination tables empty after Copy Datasets with Data Transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, stream

On BigQuery I recently started noticing an issue with Data Transfers (https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfers).

When I click on a Dataset and then on **Copy Dataset**, I want to copy a dataset from the source to the destination. I input something like the following:

[image]

```
source
project name = pA
dataset name = dA
location = EU

destination
project name = pB
dataset name = dB
location = EU

Overwrite destination tables: Selected True (tables at destination were not empty so I want to overwrite it).
```

After I click on **Copy** I monitored the status within the **Run History** in which it gave the message "The transfer has run successfully". Clicking on it I also see that each individual table was completed successfully.

Now when I go to BigQuery and I query:

```
SELECT * FROM `pB.dB.some_table` LIMIT 1000
```

I receive:

```
This query returned no results.
```

What is happening? Why is it not working anymore? Why are my tables empty at destination?

Comment: is the source table a streaming one? If yes, when did copy the dataset, 90 minutes ago  or more?

Comment: Yes indeed streaming within the last 90min

Comment: If it has been 90 minutes, try to query the table again since rows buffered by the streaming system are not immediately available for copy/export. They should become available within about 90 minutes of insertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have confirmed that the source table is a streaming table,  rows buffered by the streaming system are not immediately available for copy/export. They should become available within about [90 minutes of insertion](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability).